# active directory login in Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, active-directory

I need to login my visitors by active directory in Rails 4.
How to start session in Ruby on Rails 4 using Active Directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used these gems:

- [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)
- [devise_ldap_authenticatable](https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable)

Take care with your base configuration, it was my complication